# How to display messages from handler?

Tags: android, handler

This is my code:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg != null){
        Log.i("Working1", msg.toString());

    }
}
```

**Log.i("Working1", msg.toString());** This Logs the objects in the messages

How can I display the all content of the object or message..??
Give me any solutions..

Comment: I already try it.But no changes..

Comment: you can get mes in handler, just get your object what you sending using sendMessage()....as answered by Shashank

Comment: Actually: **this.mHandler.sendMessage(this.message);** is used for sending message

Comment: what object is message?? Better if you post your code which sending message

Comment: I think it is a JSON arraylist object..

Comment: Would be better if you provide code....edit you question.

Comment: This msg was sending from a android library function.

Comment: you may casting msg.obj in wrong object class...see in library what obj is sending in msg...

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will store your object in the `obj` field of your Message.

```
Message m = new Message();
m.obj = yourObject;
handler.sendMessage(m);
```

Inside the `handleMessage(Message msg)` function you can typecast the Message to your intended object;

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg != null){

         YourClass object = (YourClass)msg.obj;
         //Process object;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It gives an error:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
Actually:  **this.mHandler.sendMessage(this.message);** is used for sending message..

Comment: You should store the ArrayList in the obj field before sending.

Comment: Ya, it is a JSON arraylist object.

Comment: Can you post how you are sending the object. I will try to write the receiving code.